# Discord.py | How do I detect if an argument is empty? (with a if statement)

Tags: discord.py

My bot is supposed to send a error message if no arguments are passed.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True , aliases=['sl'])
async def slow (ctx, arg):
    if arg > '21600':
        await ctx.send("You are restricted to ``21600 seconds``")
    else:
        if arg ==  None:
            await ctx.send(f"Error 00: Please specify slowmode time. e.g: !slow 2")
        else:
            await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=arg)
            await ctx.send(f"Slowmode set to ``{arg}`` seconds.")
```

It isn't responding with the error message if no arguments are passed.

Answer (score 0):

2 things; 1, check if the arg is None first. 2, if arg is None, it will show up in the console as an error instead, so make the arg optional

```
@client.command(pass_context = True , aliases=['sl'])
async def slow (ctx, duration: int=None): #=None makes it optional or you can use Optional[int] and import Optional from typing
    if duration == None:
      await ctx.send(f"Error 00: Please specify slowmode time. e.g: !slow 2")
    if duration > 21600:
      await ctx.send("You are restricted to ``21600 seconds``")
    else:
      await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=duration)
      await ctx.send(f"Slowmode set to ``{duration}`` seconds.")
```

btw, I changed `arg=None` to `duration: int=None` because it's easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the argument `arg` in the function definition, like this:

```py
async def slow(ctx, arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        await ctx.send("Error! ...")
        return

    arg = int(arg)  # converts arg to an int
    # do something...
```

Also, I don't recommend using string comparisons (such as `arg > '21600'`). Instead, first convert `arg` to an `int`, then compare it with another `int` object.